# Pandas- How to deal with sub columns & merge them with rows?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Let's take a small subset of my dataframe

[image]

What I want

[image]

I keep messing this up & I have to make a time series of a much bigger dataset. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `df.stack()`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with `stack` and `unstack` to manipulate the shape of your dataframe.

Given this:

```py
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["12/20/2021"], ["National Rate", "National Rate Cap"]]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0.06, 0.82], [0.03, 0.82]],
    index=["Savings", "Interest Checking"],
    columns=columns,
)
```

You can call `unstack()` successively to beat it into shape:

```py
result = df.unstack().unstack().unstack()
result.columns = [f"{a}_{b}" for a, b in result.columns]
```

Comment: Stack then transposing might be faster than unstacking 3 times. (it's one less copy at least)`res = df.stack().T`